# Why I get an exception with df.select(dayofyear(df['Date']))['dayofyear(Date)'] but not with withColumn('Days', dayofyear(df['Date']))?

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm sorry for the long title but as it is suggested by the site, it's my question. While working on a PySpark DataFrame, I wanted to extract the days from the **Date** *column* of my **df** *DataFrame* and add it to a new *DataFrame* named **new_df**. So I wrote :

```
new_df = new_df.withColumn('Days', df.select(dayofyear(df['Date']))['dayofyear(Date)'])
```

But I got an exception saying that "Resolved attribute(s) dayofyear(Date)#5502 missing from ..." (the message is too long). But when I use :

```
new_df = new_df.withColumn('Days', dayofyear(df['Date']))
```

It works perfectly.

I hope you can help me understand why those two syntaxes are working differently.

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are making things complex - First convert the date column as per your need and return the resulted dataframe's column in a new dataframe

```
df = df.withColumn("day_of_year", F.dayofyear("Date"))
df_new = df.select("day_of_year")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's because I'm new to PySpark so I was trying things to understand the concepts. I don't know why even if in both cases we're giving columns, in the first case it isn't working but in second it is.

Comment: Understood - There are couple of online tutorials video what you can follow in order to speed up. Meanwhile, can you please accept and upvote my answer ?

Comment: Sure that's what I'm following, but they don't explain why one is true and the other is false. I already tried to upvote your answer but I can't because my reputation is lesser than 15, sorry :/